# How do I fix the pop_front and pop_back functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I am making a double linked list in C++ and I am getting an exception when I run the code. The exception is Exception Thrown: Write access violation. This->head was nullptr.

I am confused by what this means and the program crashes after this error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "My_list.h"

template<typename T>
My_list<T>::My_list()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
    empty = true;
}

template<typename T>
My_list<T>::~My_list()
{
    while (head)
    {
        My_node<T>* next_node = head->next;
        delete head;
        size--;
        head = next_node;
    }
}

template<typename T>
My_list<T>::My_list(const My_list<T>& copy_list)
{
    size = copy_list.size;
    head = copy_list.head;
    tail = copy_list.tail;
    while (copy_list.head)
    {
        My_node<T>* next = copy_list->head->next;
        head->next = copy_list->next;
        size++;
        head = next;
    }
}

template<typename T>
My_list<T>::My_list(const My_list&& new_list)
{
    //add
}


template<typename T>
void My_list<T>::push_front(T data)
{
    My_node<T>* new_node = new My_node<T>(data);
    new_node->next = nullptr;
    new_node.previous = nullptr;

    if (is_empty())
    {
        head = new_node;
        tail = head;
        size++;
        empty = false;

    }
    else
    {
        head->previous = new_node;
        new_node->next = head;
        head = new_node;
        size++;
        empty = false;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void My_list<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    My_node<T>* new_node = new My_node<T>(data);
    new_node->previous = nullptr;
    new_node->next = nullptr;

    if (is_empty())
    {
        head = new_node;
        tail = head;
        size++;
        empty = false;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = new_node;
        new_node->previous = tail;
        tail = new_node;
        size++;
        empty = false;
    }
}
template<typename T>
T My_list<T>::pop_front()
{
    if (!is_empty())
    {
        My_node<T>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        head->previous = nullptr;
        size--;
        return temp->get_data();
    }
    else
        cout << "The list is empty and cannot pop anything from it" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
T My_list<T>::pop_back()
{
    if (!is_empty())
    {
        My_node<T>* temp = tail;
        tail = tail->previous;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        size--;
        return temp->get_data();
    }
}

template<typename T>
T My_list<T>::front()
{
    return head->get_data();
}

template<typename T>
T My_list<T>::back()
{
    return tail->get_data();
}


template <typename T>
bool My_list<T>::is_empty()
{
    if (empty)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "My_list.h"
#include "My_node.h"
#include "My_node.cpp"
#include "My_list.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //list<int> list1;

    //list1.push_back(12);

    //cout << list1.front() << endl;
    My_list<int> list;
    list.push_back(22);

    cout << list.front() << endl;

    cout << "BEFORE POP" << endl;
    cout << list.pop_front() << endl;
    cout << "we did it!" << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I realize there may be other things wrong with the code that I haven't gotten to fixing yet. i just want to get the basic pop, push functions working and then can fix the other problems. Perhaps the issue is with one of my other functions like the copy constructor? If you notice anything else worth fixing that would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`pop_front` and `pop_back` *use* `is_empty()` but never *update* `empty`. So once an element is added, those methods never think the list is empty, thus the de-referencing of the null pointer.

You need to modify `pop_front` and `pop_back` to check if the list will be empty after the item removal, and if so, set `empty` to `true`.

An alternate solution would be to change `is_empty()` to look at `head` and `tail` to determine if the list is empty. This way would remove the need to have the `empty` member.

Comment: Definitely go for the "alternate solution" - the less redundant state you have, the less state can go out of sync.